# What is the best database for value history?

Tags: database

I am developing a web-crawler which crawls webshops and finds products. Currently I'm only storing a single price, the most recently found, but I'd like to store a history as well.
I'm using MariaDB (5.3.8) with InnoDB tables for the main database.

However, I'm not sure that MariaDB/MySQL might be the best database for the price history.

I'll be saving at most one price per product per day, with a data retention period of somewhere around 2-4 years.
My product table will contain around ~2 million rows which'll bring the row count for price history up to about ~730 million for a year.

This is quite a lot, methinks.

This data needs to be accessible quickly (identifiable by a numeric ID (product ID) or a SHA1 hash value, whatever is better/easier).

The data that needs to be saved is simply:

product_id, price, date (no time!)

There will be heavy load on the database software handling it, since INSERTs would be happening quite often and SELECTs would happen equally as often, if not more often.
Data aggregation to another database every once in a while is a possibility for the purpose of minimizing SELECT queries, but I'd prefer to avoid it so as not to add another layer of 'helper scripts'.

There will be no DELETEs performed at all.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy scenario for any RDBMS. Just inserts into this narrow table with 1-2 indexes on it is no problem at all. 730m rows per year is also totally fine (I'd like to know how big the data will be in terms of GBs - probably 10-20GB?).

You should choose based on strategic concerns. Which RDBMS do you already have and use? What are you familiar with? What about backup, high-availability?

Comment: At least one index is needed on (product_id, date) since there should only be one value per day per product.

I stated everything you're asking in my question.
Backup is relevant, high availability is partially relevant.

Comment: These were rhetoric questions in the sense that I wanted to say that DML performance does not matter for you. You should only decide based on these question. In that sense I recommend that you just use the RDBMS you have.